# What is the proper length of the Tefilin Shel Rosh straps?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, shiurim-measurements

How long are the Tefilin Shel Rosh straps supposed to be? What is the minimum Shiur and what is the maximum?

Comment: If we are talking about the length of the straps it worth mentioning that the straps should be of different length, I mean one shorter then another. Don't know what is the source for that.

Comment: @jutky, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9229

Answer (score 5):

The *bar mitzva* volume of *Nit'ei Gavri'el* [#52](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46541&st=&pgnum=305) quotes the following practices:

- Some say the straps should reach the legs. (*Mishna B'rura* 27:35)
- Some say the right strap should reach below the belt and the left to the navel. (*Shulchan Aruch* 27:11)
- Some say the right strap should reach the navel and the left to the chest. (*Tur* 27)

The latter two sound like neither maxima nor minima, but exact preferable ranges.

Comment: I don't see any such claim in the Shulchan Arukh there. He just quotes the Rambam cited in zaq's answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Rambam](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925424/jewish/Chapter-Three.htm)

> The length of the straps of the head tefillin should be sufficient to
>   surround the head, tie the knot, and extend on either side of the head
>   until they reach the navel or slightly above it.