# Wrapping tefillin to create letters

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, tefilin

When we wrap, there seems to be a prevalent custom to incorporate the [shapes](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/how-to-put-on-tefillin/) Dalet, Yod and Shin in the strap on the hand/arm (depending on one's custom (discussed in Sefer Ta'amei Haminhagim page 13 and diagrams pp. 621-626) (Minhagei Yeshurun P. 212). While I know that there are kabbalistic sources and [other](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/479863/jewish/Why-is-the-tefillin-wrapped-seven-times.htm) explanations for the seven wrappings around the arm, and that many of the laws are reputed to be unexplained as examples of halacha [lemoshe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9264/1362) misinai, I am wondering where the idea of spelling out God's name with the 3 letters comes from (and I don't have access to the Otzar Minhagei Yeshurun and the Ktzot hashulchan).

A quick look at printed alphabets  of ancient Hebrew show that the shape of the letters is not the same as we have now so wrapping straps to mimic current shapes would indicate that the minhagim are relatively recent. Where does this idea/practice originate?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59960/759 which claims to use old shaped letters.

Comment: @DoubleAA I just watched the video which does help (and now I have to watch that question to see what history people dig up) but then this seems to point even more clearly to a more modern and disconnected minhag to tie them following the shapes we do now, and I am still looking for the source to wrap in those 3 letters.

Comment: Are the shapes of the letters that we wrap different than the letters in the tefilin parchments themselves that make them more recent? How so?

Comment: @Yishai I assume they are the same, but that just leads to a question about when the script changed (answers like this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18083/1362 and the others to that question) come into play.

Comment: @Danno, yes, but then what is the last paragraph of your question? What is "relatively recent"? I'm not following. If you think Ezra changed it to Ksav Ashuris, then wrapping could have been contemporaneous with that. If you think it is older, then wrapping could have been older too. I'm just not following.

Comment: @Yishai that's the second part of my question (the first being the source for sh/d/y) -- do we have any knowledge of whether the wrapping in the shape of current letters is ancient or relatively recent? Is it the function of a change in the written alphabet or is it a vestige of or proof for an older written alphabet which is much like ours today?

Comment: @Danno teimonim and safaradim wrap in "ancient hebrew" kathav ivrith.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob is that sourced earlier than the era Yishai mentions in his answer? If so, do you have more information on the history of it?

Comment: @Danno dont know gotta check my sources. but i know for fact teimonim make tafillin like the rambam/jaonim and tie probably like them to

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob please check -- if the Teimanim made (wrapped?) like Geonim, then Yishai's source's claim has a problem.

Answer (score 5):

The [Tashbatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_ben_Zemah_Duran) writes in [3:118](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42132&st=&pgnum=396&hilite=) that the custom of wrapping the Shin Dalet Yud on the Arm Tefillin is not of Talmudic or Gaonic origin and was not the custom of his teachers, nor the German, French, Provincial or Catolina custom. It originated in Spain as an expression of the love of the Mitzvah - and he takes no issue with it.

He then points out that the Shin Dalet Yud was already present in the Tefilin, with the Shin on the Shel Rosh, the Dalet as the knot on the Shel Rosh, and the Yud of the knot next to the Tefilin Shel Yad.

This latter notion of the name, is tied in with [Devarim 28:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9992/jewish/Chapter-28.htm#showrashi=true&v=10) as outlined in the Talmud [Munachos 35b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=35b&format=pdf) and Rashi there.