# What do the different chassidish tefillin tying on the palm and hand mean, what sects uses them?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, shacharis-morning-prayer, chasidut-hasidism

I have noticed many different styles of wrapping tefillin over the hand, fingers, and palm, as seen below.

My question is what is the significance of this, and who does this, and is it something specific to a certain Chassidus?

*Note my question is only about the difference in terms of Sefard style and not Ashkenazi and Sepharadi

[image: Like this]

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59986/wrapping-tefillin-to-create-letters

Comment: Note your middle image is clearly someone using paint to draw scribbles

Comment: My brother-in-law showed me he wraps the tefillin so the shin is face inward toward him, while I learned to wrap so it's facing outward.

Comment: @robev I was wondering what sect that was, it looked complicated xD

Comment: @robev  hahhahaha

Answer (score -1):

Reishit Chachmah, Shaar HaKedushah, ch. 6 (on Sefaria it's number 103)

> ואגב מבואר שהרצועה שאנו כורכין באצבע היא טבעת הקידושין שהזכר נותן לה, ומכאן היה אומר מורי ע"ה שאין ראוי לכרוך הרצועה על האצבע עד שיניח תפלה של ראש שהוא סוד הזכר, שאם עדיין לא בא הזכר קדושין מהיכן, וכן מנהג רוב ישראל, ואין ראוי לשנות המנהג. וכן היה אומר מורי ע"ה שכריכה זו שבאצבע צריך שתהיה מעומד, שהזכר המקדש את האשה מקדש אותה מעומד, שהקדושין הם מעלמא דדכורא, ודרכו מעומד. והכריכות צריכות שיהיו ג' כדפי' ברעיא מהימנא (פ' פנחס דף רכח ע"ב), והעתקנו לשונו לעיל

The Pesukim we say while wrapping also correspond to the encircling that's done under the Chuppa. Since "Varastich"  is mentioned 3 times in the passuk we wrap it 3 times around the finger.

I've seen some who say that is why we use the middle finger as that used to be the ring finger (I believe today most use the 4th finger).

Along these lines, if you look at all the different versions, they all have the basic 3 times around the finger and then either an additional 2 which equals 3 counting the first finger, or an additional 3 rings around the fingers or circling first 1 finger then 2 then 3 etc. But they all seem to work in sets of 3's.

Comment: The three times around the middle finger are universal, done by all Chasidish, Ashkenazi, Sefardi, and Teimani traditions, AFAIK. The question is about the Shin wrappings and additional nuances.

Comment: The shin is also almost universal, with a variation of direction. The differences I've seen, and shown in the pictures are aside from the shin and middle finger.

Comment: No, Sefardim and Teimanim don't make a shin, nor Chabad. I remember seeing in kisvei Ari specifically not to make a shin.

Comment: Interesting. All the pictures in the OP seem to have it

Comment: @Mordechai in the case of lubavitch chasidim and teimanim, the shin is made further up the arm by wrapping the strap over the box. this is true in many sefardi traditions as well

Comment: Sefaradim often don't make a shin or a yod because the yod is the knot right outside the arm box, and the shin is on the outside of the tefillin shel rosh. However I have seen some teimanim make a shin now on the arm, but I didn't witness a yod or a dalet being made anywhere

Comment: @Mordechai could you point to exactly where in kisve Arizal you saw not to make a shin on one's hand? thank you